# Save variable from my PC to .txt file on Remote Windows Server using Python + WMI

Tags: python, variables, server, wmi

I have a Python script on my PC with the variable `x`. I would like to write `x`'s value to a .txt file on Remote Windows Server 2019.

I launched this Python code on my PC:

```
import wmi

x = 28
c = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
process_id, return_value = c.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine=f"cmd.exe /c set x={x} & echo %x% > c:/1.txt")
```

Connection works fine but I expected that the file `c:/1.txt` on the remote server would contain the value of the variable `x`, i.e. the number `28`, but the .txt file "c:/1.txt" on the Remote Windows Server contains `%x%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using an f-string, its probably better to forgo the shell variable and format `x` into the `echo` command directly:

```
import wmi

x = 28
c = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
process_id, return_value = c.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine=f"echo {x} > c:/1.txt")
```